How to extract air bubbles from arctic ice to measure CO2 concentration?
I read an article about how the CO$_2$ concentration changed in the least 500k years, based on the analysis of air bubbles trapped in Arctic ice.
I came to wonder how the bubbles were extracted for further analysis. It must be a way that ensures that the surrounding air does not interfere.
Since it has been about 30 years I had a course on measurement (which, to be frank, I slept through) I vaguely imagine that it must be a combination of deep freezing (to slow down melting and liquify gases) and pumping the surrounding air -- something along the lines of

put the sample in a closed recipient
deep freeze it to possibly liquefy some gazes (to be discarded)
pump out the air to get "vacuum" (where "vacuum" is defined according to the requested uncertainty in the measurement)
raise the temperature to melt the external layer - to account for gas that adheres, st the same time pumping out the air (the deep freeze should ensure that something is left of the sample)

I am genuinely curious how you actually extract these bubbles with a good chance of not introducing surrounding CO$_2$.

You put the sample in a cryogenic UHV chamber or at least cryogenic sample holder (e.g. -200°C, $<10^{-6}$mbar) with a mass spectrometer attached to the chamber. Then you slowly melt or rather evaporate the ice (e.g. by illumination or a heater) and do a live analysis of the evaporating gases.
Of course you are not interested in the water itself, but anything not water will be constituents of the trapped gases inside the ice. A mass spectrometer allows to measure the relative concentrations of the detected species. For extremely low concentrations you might want to improve sensitivity by applying a chopper to your measurements to have the ability to subtract the background.
